# Checking file before uploading react error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mime-types

I'm trying to check the selected file type before uploading it to the server, but I get a weird error on compiling.

Getting file:

```
            <Button
                  id="UploadButton"
                  component="label"
                  htmlFor="fileInput"
                >
                  Upload Media{" "}
                  <input
                    id="fileInput"
                    type="file"
                    hidden
                    required
                    onChange={filePickerHandler}
                  />
                </Button>
```

fileHandler:

```
  const [file, setFile] = useState("");

  const filePickerHandler = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setFile(event.target.files[0]);
 };
```

TypeChecker:

```
  const checkFileType = (file)=>{

    if(file.type.match("image.*"))
    return "image";

    if(file.type.match('video.*'))
    return 'video';

    if(file.type.match('audio.*'))
    return 'audio';

  return 'Not Supported';}
```

After compiling the project, I get this:

[image]

I would be appreciated if one of you can help me.

Comment: When you're using `checkFileType` ?

Comment: After user selects the file to upload and setFile.@MajidM.

Comment: In your `checkFileType` function first check if the file is not null or undefined before doing the type checks like so, `if(!file) return;`

Comment: @Ahmadreza Are you sending `event.target.files[0]` as a parameter to `checkFileType`?

Comment: @MajidM. Yes, but after `setFile` it to file. then I passed `file`

Comment: @HassanAzzam Thanks, worked fine.

Comment: @Ahmadreza If you attach the full code, I will say more certain what's the problem. But I think that it's because of you're using the `file` state which is not set yet. Because `setFile` is asynchronous and you should use `useEffect` for your aim.

Comment: @MajidM. I fixed it with `if(!file) return;` this solution, thanks by the way